# Check that all HealthIndicator avaliable on application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Currently, Actuator doesn't check that all indicators in groups available in context, it also skips not existing indicators while runtime checks.

For example, application.yaml - if I describe *checkServiceUnknown*

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      group:
        readiness:
          include: checkService1, checkServiceUnknown
```

It just skip *checkServiceUnknown* in HealthEndpointSupport. It happens because it loop by NamedContributor, not by group members:

```
for (NamedContributor<C> namedContributor : namedContributors) {
            String name = namedContributor.getName();
            C contributor = namedContributor.getContributor();
            if (group.isMember(name) || isNested) {
...
```

How to check that all described indicators really will be called/available on Spring startup?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround

```
@Autowired
HealthEndpointProperties healthEndpointProperties;

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Set<String> healthContributors = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(HealthContributor.class).keySet().stream()
            .map(HealthContributorNameFactory.INSTANCE)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    healthEndpointProperties.getGroup().values().stream()
            .flatMap(it -> it.getInclude().stream())
            .forEach(it -> {
                if (!healthContributors.contains(it)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown health indicator " + it);
                }
            });
}
```